# OnCompletion() in Apache Camel is called more than once

Tags: java, apache-camel

In routeBuilder class it is having many routes, after completion of all routes need to call testMethod() but currently testMethod() method is calling many times

```
 .onCompletion().bean(TestProcessor.class,"testMethod").end()
```

//Router Class

```
     from(Source).setHeader("message", 

    body()).onCompletion().bean(TestProcessor.class,"testMethod").end().
    choice().when(header("camelfilenameonly").contains("test1.csv"))
   .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv,Test1CsvDto.class).bean(TestProcessor.class,
                        "processTest1Object").stop()

                .otherwise().choice()
                .when(header("camelfilenameonly").contains("test2.csv"))
                //Unmarshal csv
                .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Test2CsvDto.class).bean(TestProcessor.class,
                        "processTest2").stop()
```

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: can you put the full route definition

Comment: Route definition code changes added above...

Comment: I tested the route locally and the everything works fine. The onCompletion method is called once per route execution. (Sidemark: I removed the bindy party to simplify it)

Comment: In my case, In the above code snippet testMethod() is calling twice even it is single route.

Comment: I just recreated your full route even with the bindy part and everything works as expected. See my code: https://gist.github.com/gysel/9fe8a2eeb2f8ab731256d3329fd7d289

Comment: thanks for the reply, for you how many times the testMethod() is invoking in the above case.