# OnCompletion in Apache Camel for entire file completion

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have routes and multiple processes for a file processing.What I am trying to achieve is if I place a file, after output file creation I want to rename the created file in onCompeltion() code.But onCompletion code is triggered for all the routes.But I want to do that at the end of a specific file process of all routes.Please help me to achieve this.I tried this link [OnCompletion() in Apache Camel is called more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237756/oncompletion-in-apache-camel-is-called-more-than-once) too.I want to rename the file in onCompletion each of the file process is completed

**Router:**

```
@Component
public class MyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                onCompletion().process((exchange)->{System.out.println("File is processed");});

                from("file:src/main/resources/in?delete=true").routeId("route1").process((exchange) -> {
                    List<Customer> names = new ArrayList<>();
                    names.add(new Customer("first1","last1"));
                    names.add(new Customer("first2","last2"));
                    names.add(new Customer("first3","last3"));
                    System.out.println("total customers:"+names.size());
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
                }).split(simple("${body}")).to("direct:process1");

                from("direct:findAndProcess").routeId("findAndProcess").choice()
                .when().simple("${body.getFirstName} == 'first1'").to("direct:process1")
                .otherwise().to("direct:process2");

                from("direct:process1").routeId("process1").process((exchange) -> {
                    System.out.println("current process1 customer:"+exchange.getIn().getBody(Customer.class).toString());
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(Customer.class).toString());
                }).to("direct:write2file");

                from("direct:process2").routeId("process2").process((exchange) -> {
                    System.out.println("current process2 customer:"+exchange.getIn().getBody(Customer.class).toString());
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(Customer.class).toString());
                }).to("direct:write2file");

                from("direct:write2file").routeId("write2file").to("file:src/main/resources/out?fileName=test_out.txt&fileExist=Append");       
    }
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
total customers:3
current process1 customer:first1:::last1
File is processed
File is processed
current process1 customer:first2:::last2
File is processed
File is processed
current process1 customer:first3:::last3
File is processed
File is processed
File is processed
```

**Expected:**

```
total customers:3
current process1 customer:first1:::last1
current process1 customer:first2:::last2
current process1 customer:first3:::last3
File is processed
```

**Updated Code Snippet working:**

```
from("file:src/main/resources/in?delete=true").routeId("route1").process((exchange) -> {
    List<Customer> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(new Customer("first1", "last1"));
    names.add(new Customer("first2", "last2"));
    names.add(new Customer("first3", "last3"));
    System.out.println("total customers:" + names.size());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
}).split(simple("${body}")).to("direct:findAndProcess").end().process((exchange) -> {
    System.out.println("File is processed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it after the splitter

```
from
   split
     to direct:1
   end // end of splitter
   process // here you can rename the file, but you can also just use the move option on the file endpoint
```

Also have you seen you can configure the file endpoint itself to rename the file after its done, its the `move` option. See more in the Camel docs

Comment: Thanks for answer +1, end splitter is working I updated the question with answer.Please check also could you give me link for move option.I tried but could find?

Comment: See the file doc at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc